# Mesibo sdk integration issues in cocoa pods

Tags: mesibo

[Xcode console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MUrM.png)

I'm facing an error to work with the mesibo cocoa pods please help my Xcode is 11.0 and mac os is 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

The linking error with `__darwin_check_fd_set_overflow` is an issue with Xcode 11.3.1 (and 11.0 too i think). Try Xcode 12 (beta) or Xcode 11.5.